# Ruby Gem pi_piper crashing with bcm2835_init: gpio mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory, anyone else seen this?

Tags: ruby, mcp3008

I am running ruby 3.0.3 on Raspbian 11 on raspberry pi 4b and I am trying to use adc mcp3008 using [pi_piper gem](https://github.com/jwhitehorn/pi_piper/tree/master) and whenever I initialize a pin `clock = PiPiper::Pin.new :pin => 18, :direction => :out` I get `bcm2835_init: gpio mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory` error with full memory dump

I know a lot of people are doing ruby with Raspberry PI, which is a shame, but if anyone out there has any hits it be great.

Full dump:

```
irb(main):003:0> clock = PiPiper::Pin.new :pin => 18, :direction => :out
bcm2835_init: gpio mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin.rb:120: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000093
ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0025 p:---- s:0127 e:000126 CFUNC  :pin_set_pud
c:0024 p:0136 s:0121 e:000120 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin.rb:120
c:0023 p:0234 s:0116 e:000115 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin.rb:60 [FINISH]
c:0022 p:---- s:0111 e:000110 CFUNC  :new
c:0021 p:0019 s:0106 E:0011e4 EVAL   (irb):3 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0102 e:000101 CFUNC  :eval
c:0019 p:0020 s:0094 e:000093 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:116
c:0018 p:0059 s:0086 e:000084 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/context.rb:450
c:0017 p:0163 s:0077 e:000076 BLOCK  /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:567
c:0016 p:0024 s:0072 e:000071 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:751
c:0015 p:0007 s:0066 e:000065 BLOCK  /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:548
c:0014 p:0123 s:0061 e:000060 BLOCK  /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:251 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0057 e:000056 CFUNC  :loop
c:0012 p:0005 s:0053 e:000052 BLOCK  /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233 [FINISH]
c:0011 p:---- s:0050 e:000049 CFUNC  :catch
c:0010 p:0010 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232
c:0009 p:0046 s:0041 E:0012fc METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:547
c:0008 p:0004 s:0036 e:000035 BLOCK  /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:481 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0033 e:000032 CFUNC  :catch
c:0006 p:0058 s:0028 E:001228 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:480
c:0005 p:0104 s:0022 e:000021 METHOD /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:409
c:0004 p:0019 s:0016 e:000015 TOP    /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.5/exe/irb:11 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0013 e:000012 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0112 s:0008 E:002660 EVAL   /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/irb:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:0013d0 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.5/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:409:in `start'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:480:in `run'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:480:in `catch'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:481:in `block in run'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:547:in `eval_input'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `each_top_level_statement'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `catch'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `loop'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:251:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:548:in `block in eval_input'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:751:in `signal_status'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:567:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/context.rb:450:in `evaluate'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:116:in `evaluate'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:116:in `eval'
(irb):3:in `<main>'
(irb):3:in `new'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin.rb:60:in `initialize'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin.rb:120:in `pull!'
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin.rb:120:in `pin_set_pud'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 "r0: 0x00000093 "r1: 0x00000000 "r2: 0x00000000 "r3: 0x00000000 "r4: 0x00000012
 "r5: 0xb3f22a58 "r6: 0x00000002 "r7: 0x00e44c1c "r8: 0x00000002 "r9: 0xbec59088
 "r1: 0xbec5908c "sp: 0xbec59088 "fa: 0x00000093

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: irb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 ruby2_keywords.rb
    5 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/enc/encdb.so
    6 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/enc/trans/transdb.so
    7 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/rbconfig.rb
    8 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    9 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
   10 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
   11 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
   12 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   13 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   14 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   15 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/text.rb
   16 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   17 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb
   18 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
   19 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   20 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
   21 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   22 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   23 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/util.rb
   24 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   25 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   26 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/monitor.so
   27 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb
   28 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   29 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb
   30 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   31 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb
   32 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb
   33 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/version.rb
   34 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb
   35 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb
   36 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb
   37 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checker.rb
   38 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/class_name_checker.rb
   39 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb
   40 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb
   41 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb
   42 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/key_error_checker.rb
   43 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/null_checker.rb
   44 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/tree_spell_checker.rb
   45 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/require_path_checker.rb
   46 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean/formatters/plain_formatter.rb
   47 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/did_you_mean.rb
   48 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/tsort/lib/tsort.rb
   49 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/tsort.rb
   50 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/request_set/gem_dependency_api.rb
   51 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/request_set/lockfile/parser.rb
   52 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/request_set/lockfile/tokenizer.rb
   53 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/request_set/lockfile.rb
   54 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/request_set.rb
   55 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/gem_metadata.rb
   56 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb
   57 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/errors.rb
   58 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/action.rb
   59 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_edge_no_circular.rb
   60 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_vertex.rb
   61 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/delete_edge.rb
   62 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/detach_vertex_named.rb
   63 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/set_payload.rb
   64 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/tag.rb
   65 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/log.rb
   66 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/vertex.rb
   67 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph.rb
   68 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/state.rb
   69 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/specification_provider.rb
   70 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/resolution_state.rb
   71 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb
   72 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb
   73 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/ui.rb
   74 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo.rb
   75 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo.rb
   76 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/activation_request.rb
   77 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/conflict.rb
   78 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/dependency_request.rb
   79 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/requirement_list.rb
   80 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/stats.rb
   81 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/set.rb
   82 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb
   83 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb
   84 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb
   85 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/current_set.rb
   86 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/git_set.rb
   87 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/index_set.rb
   88 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb
   89 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/lock_set.rb
   90 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/vendor_set.rb
   91 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/source_set.rb
   92 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb
   93 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/spec_specification.rb
   94 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/api_specification.rb
   95 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/git_specification.rb
   96 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/index_specification.rb
   97 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/installed_specification.rb
   98 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/local_specification.rb
   99 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/lock_specification.rb
  100 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver/vendor_specification.rb
  101 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/resolver.rb
  102 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/source/git.rb
  103 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/source/installed.rb
  104 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/source/specific_file.rb
  105 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/source/local.rb
  106 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/source/lock.rb
  107 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/source/vendor.rb
  108 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/source.rb
  109 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/set.rb
  110 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/ripper.so
  111 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/ripper/core.rb
  112 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/ripper/lexer.rb
  113 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/ripper/filter.rb
  114 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/ripper/sexp.rb
  115 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/ripper.rb
  116 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/io/console.so
  117 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/timeout.rb
  118 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/forwardable/impl.rb
  119 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/forwardable.rb
  120 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/version.rb
  121 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/config.rb
  122 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/key_actor/base.rb
  123 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/key_actor/emacs.rb
  124 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/key_actor/vi_command.rb
  125 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/key_actor/vi_insert.rb
  126 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/key_actor.rb
  127 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/key_stroke.rb
  128 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/kill_ring.rb
  129 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/unicode/east_asian_width.rb
  130 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/unicode.rb
  131 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/delegate.rb
  132 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb
  133 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/etc.so
  134 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tmpdir.rb
  135 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tempfile.rb
  136 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/line_editor.rb
  137 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/history.rb
  138 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/ansi.rb
  139 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/general_io.rb
  140 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline.rb
  141 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/init.rb
  142 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/workspace.rb
  143 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/inspector.rb
  144 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/src_encoding.rb
  145 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/magic-file.rb
  146 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb
  147 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/completion.rb
  148 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/input-method.rb
  149 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/output-method.rb
  150 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/context.rb
  151 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/extend-command.rb
  152 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/locale.rb
  153 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/color.rb
  154 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/version.rb
  155 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/easter-egg.rb
  156 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb
  157 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/prettyprint.rb
  158 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pp.rb
  159 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/color_printer.rb
  160 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb
  161 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/enc/trans/single_byte.so
  162 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/rubyeventmachine.so
  163 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/version.rb
  164 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/pool.rb
  165 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/deferrable.rb
  166 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/future.rb
  167 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/streamer.rb
  168 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/spawnable.rb
  169 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/processes.rb
  170 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/iterator.rb
  171 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/buftok.rb
  172 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/timers.rb
  173 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/protocols.rb
  174 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/connection.rb
  175 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/callback.rb
  176 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/queue.rb
  177 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/channel.rb
  178 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/file_watch.rb
  179 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/process_watch.rb
  180 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/tick_loop.rb
  181 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/resolver.rb
  182 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/completion.rb
  183 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/em/threaded_resource.rb
  184 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/shellwords.rb
  185 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/socket.so
  186 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/armv7l-linux-eabihf/io/wait.so
  187 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/socket.rb
  188 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/securerandom.rb
  189 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/resolv.rb
  190 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9/lib/eventmachine.rb
  191 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/frequency.rb
  192 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/i2c.rb
  193 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin_values.rb
  194 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin.rb
  195 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pin_error.rb
  196 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/platform.rb
  197 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/pwm.rb
  198 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/spi.rb
  199 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/stub_driver.rb
  200 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/version.rb
  201 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper.rb
  202 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.so
  203 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/platform.rb
  204 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/data_converter.rb
  205 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/types.rb
  206 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/library.rb
  207 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/errno.rb
  208 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/abstract_memory.rb
  209 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/pointer.rb
  210 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/memorypointer.rb
  211 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct_layout.rb
  212 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct_layout_builder.rb
  213 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct_by_reference.rb
  214 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct.rb
  215 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/union.rb
  216 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/managedstruct.rb
  217 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/callback.rb
  218 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/io.rb
  219 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/autopointer.rb
  220 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/variadic.rb
  221 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/enum.rb
  222 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/version.rb
  223 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/ffi.rb
  224 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb
  225 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper/bcm2835.rb




Aborted
```

Comment: You will probably get help quicker from the gem author.

Comment: yeah I wasnt sure as the repo hasnt been touched in 5 years :( but reading his readme help, should of done that first.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, I had to update the c lib that the gem uses in the background.

```
wget http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.71.tar.gz
tar zxvf bcm2835-1.71.tar.gz && cd bcm2835-1.71
./configure && make
sudo make check
sudo make install
cd src && cc -shared bcm2835.o -o libbcm2835.so
cp libbcm2835.so ~/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-1.9.9/lib/pi_piper
cp libbcm2835.so ~/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pi_piper-2.0.0/lib/pi_piper
```